# Having difficulty with datePicker in python-django project

Tags: python, html, django, datepicker

The Django web-app project I am working on has numerous apps.  I am creating a new app with forms. The forms use `datePicker`. The `datePicker` class is referenced in an `attrs{}` block. On my new form I have exactly the same format as forms used in other parts of the project, but the `datePicker` refuses to display.

The application uses `Bootstrap 3` and `javascript/css`, but neither of the latter are referenced in the template.  Code is below. I am relatively new to django, and it is not clear to me why this doesn't work. Some part of the is missing, but I can't identify it.

What am I missing in this code?

template.html:

```
{% extends 'common/base.html' %} {% load menu_tags %} {% load static %}
 
{% block page_title %}Add New Project{% endblock %}
 
{% block content %}
 
<h2 class="sub-header">Add New Project</h2> <form method="POST"
class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% load bootstrap3 %}
 
     {# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
     {% bootstrap_messages %}
     {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal"  %}
     {% buttons layout='horizontal' %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
         {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
     </button>
     {% endbuttons %}
 
 </form>
 
 <!-- <A href='{%  url "projects:projects_list" %}'>back to list</A> -->
 
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.datepicker').datepicker({
             format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
             autoclose: true,
         });
 
         $('.timepicker').timepicker({
             format: 'hh:ii:ss',
             autoclose: true,
             showMeridian: false,
         });
 
         $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
             showClear: true
         });
     }); </script>
 
 {{ form.media }}
 
 {% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
import datetime
 
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from django import forms 
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe 
from .models import Project, Protocol 
from dal import autocomplete
 
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"
        protocol_nbr = forms.ModelChoiceField(
          queryset=Protocol.objects.order_by('protocol_nbr').values_list('protocol_nbr', flat=True).distinct(),
            label='',
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2'}),
        )
        widgets = {
            'created':forms.DateInput(#format='%m/%d/%Y',
                 attrs={'class': 'datePicker'}), 
                   'placeholder':'mm/dd/yyyy',         
                   'autofill': False,    
                   'autocomplete':'false'}),
           'modified': forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y',
                attrs={'class': 'datePicker',
                    'placeholder':'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    'autofill': False,
                    'autocomplete':'false'}),
        } [...]
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting.  The SOF editor didn't handle the block-quotes as I expected.